# How to make finder launch to the previously closed location, on startup?

Tags: macos, finder, mojave

My wife has just updated her OS to `Mojave`. She believes that prior to this update, she could close finder window, reopen it and find that all her `tabs` were restored. That is, she thinks that Finder was saving her "session", allowing  for her to close finder, only to have that last session restored.

I am not sure about this - I do not remember this feature, although my memory is rather... what was I saying?

Anyway, if any of you have some insight/knowledge or solution I'd appreciate hearing it.

Comment: @Buscar웃 Great, any idea how to restore that feature with `OS Mojave`?

Comment: You can use the Go -> Recent Folders function if a better solution isn't found.

Comment: @Christian Thanks - I've mentioned that to her but I got a death stare in return.

Comment: I've done some experiments to no avail. Maybe someone else can look into this? It seems to be related to the "Resume" featured and involves permissions and folders in the `~/Library/Saved Application State/com.apple.finder.savedState` and possibly the terminal command `defaults write com.apple.finder NSQuitAlwaysKeepsWindows -bool true`

Comment: I'm not understanding the "close Finder" aspect of this question. Unless you're forcing it to quit & stay quit, Finder never 'closes' between boot up & shutdown. System Prefs > General > 'Close windows when quitting an app' is the pref pretty much in charge of whether apps retain their state between launches.

Comment: @UnassumingGuy Thanks - tried those but they did not work for me, either.

Comment: @Tetsujin `close finder`, not `quit` finder; just close it by hitting the red `x`.

Comment: Buscar already made the edit - that's simply closing a Finder window, not closing Finder.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the solution to the OS Mojave, Finder problem

- Click on top-left Apple icon
- Then click on System Preferences
- Then General
- And then uncheck the box saying, "`Close windows when quitting an app`"
- It will save your session of Finder and when you restart your system it will show you last opened tabs of the session

> NOTE: before Shut Down or Restart of the system, don't close the
>   Finder

[image: Mojave Finder solution]