# How do I turn off "Close windows when quitting an app" with `defaults write`?

Tags: macos, command-line

It's easy to [manually turn off the "Close windows when quitting an app"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/349500) feature, but how do I do it in a script with `defaults write`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you haven't found yet, try this (works on Mojave at least) :

- Enable : defaults write NSGlobalDomain NSQuitAlwaysKeepsWindows -bool
  false
- Disable : defaults write NSGlobalDomain NSQuitAlwaysKeepsWindows
  -bool true

Have a nice day

Comment: [Great improvement on the app specific cases](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/24956/5472) by using NSGlobalDomain key.

Comment: You have these backwards.  You turn OFF "Close windows when quitting an app" by setting `NSQuitAlwaysKeepsWindows` to `true`.  The feature's name in the UI is the inverse of the setting in the preferences storage.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>The other answer gives the right raw materials but is exactly backwards.</strike>

You turn OFF "Close windows when quitting an app" like this:

`defaults write NSGlobalDomain NSQuitAlwaysKeepsWindows -bool true`

**UPDATE: the other answer was *originally* correct, as the author composed it, but a moderator "corrected" it 4 minutes later to make it backwards.**  I've restored it as the accepted answer.  Please up-vote the other one.  (You can upvote mine *too* if you want, to thank me for noticing the moderator's error, but please *at least* give credit to the original author for finding the correct information.)

Comment: This also opens up an option that isn't possible via the GUI... want _only QuickTime_ to keep its windows when quitting the app? Replace `NSGlobalDomain` with `com.apple.QuickTime` in the above answer! :D

Comment: My initial answer was right, but has been changed the wrong way then.  Sorry for that. See my comments on it.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback and update :D